# Изгиб внутрь блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

надо сверстать такой navbar, а идей как это сделать нету.

Расскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такой изгиб во внутрь div-а, чтоб он огибал кнопку и если есть какие нибудь статьи или видео по тому, как этому научиться, отправьте, пожалуйста.
[image: Изгиб]

---

https://youtu.be/McrMC3SXhUU

Тут всё круто сделано. Кому надо, держите)

Comment: Своих идей и попыток - ноль? Тогда изучаем: _псевдоэлементы_, _градиенты и фон_, _mask_, _clip-path_, _drop-shadow_... А лучше сразу SVG.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать такой вырез у фигуры?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098306/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b)